# How to escape an html tag in Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a `View` in `ASP.NET MVC`, I need to type following line of text:

"< h t m l > This is how you escape an HTML tag in Razor < / h t m l >"

Please remove spaces from < h t m l > to consider it a proper html tag.

How do I accomplish it? All answers are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
  @{ var myHtmlString = new HtmlString("<html> This is how you escape an HTML tag in Razor </html>");}
  @Html.Encode(myHtmlString)
```

Prints

[image]

Another Simple Way is :

```
  @Html.Encode(Html.Raw("<html> This is how you escape an HTML tag in Razor </html>"));
```

gives same output as above.

Comment: OK this is correct. Thank you for the answer and help. Hmm, do you know whats the difference between `string x ="hi";` and `var x = new HtmlString("hi");`.

Comment: `HtmlString` is the raw format of `string`. You can see the difference only when you have `html tags` in the string.  `@Html.Raw(string)` return `@HtmlString(string)`.